# Can I set media to be played on the startup in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-13.04

Can I set media to be played on the startup in Ubuntu 13.04? I mean when the ubuntu is starting up can i set music or video or at least a photo to be shown on start up? I had a trouble doing this on an older version of ubuntu. Now I am using 13.04

Comment: is it before or after login that the media should be shown ?

Comment: When logging in (after giving the correct password)